# How to type key in object or pass them correctly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that takes an array of objects and a key from the object and returns an array of objects with a key of 2 parameters and a value from the object. For some reason, when specifying the TS object, it perceives the key as a string and not the key from the object

```
  const getArrayByKey = <T, V extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: V): { [key in V]: T[V] }[] => {
       return array.map((item) => ({ [key]: item[key] }))
    }
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJd8l.png)

If i pass in function array with objects like { id : 1, title : '123'} and 2 parameter 'id', i want to get array with objects like { id : 1} only with id(2 parameter of function), type in returned array works correctly but i get error when return in map function { [key] : item[key] } because key is perceived as a string but not id.

Upd: I fix this error just add explicit indication to object in map function

```
return array.map((item) => ({ [key]: item[key] } as { [key in V] : T[V]}))
```

Maybe there is another way to implicitly indicate?

Comment: What do you mean by `array of objects with a key of 2 parameters and a value from the object`? You cannot type array key types, also it is unclear what does `value from the object` mean.

Comment: If i pass in function array with objects like { id : 1, title : '123'} and 2 parameter 'id', i want to get array with objects like { id : 1} only with id(2 parameter of function), type in returned array works correctly but i get error when return { [key] : item[key] } because key is perceived as a string but not id

Comment: Thanks for explanation. FYI it's better to include detailed explanation in the post itself, because it can be lost in the comments section.

Comment: I fix this error just add `  return array.map((item) => ({ [key]: item[key] } as { [key in V] : T[V]})) ` , but maybe there is another way to implicitly indicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
const getArrayByKey = <T, V extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: V): Pick<T, V>[] => {
    return array.map((item) => ({ [key]: item[key] }) as Pick<T, V>)
};
```

See it working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygQQE6oIYE8BCWDSCWMAvDADwAqANDAGowIAeUCYAJhDANZEgBmMSgD4AFBnTYAXEIDaAXVq8sMugEoZABQCWwblVp1hC0sJgBvAFAwbMVEgCuqMDAmYsAOgC2GAA6jRbVYvNVMYUXMYWWV5GSCEL2iieRgAX1CMLh09A3phNUtUgG5LS1BIWH4QEFILGG12GQBGACYAZloIEC8kAAttMDgZACJWtuG0kvLoGAAjCVrEFElcAiJRWSqQRRhhhuG1ErLwLoAbBA9TkDhRedRDyyA)

Comment: Yeah, this looks more readable, but maybe there is a way to solve this without `as`, i think its not possible

Comment: Couldn't also find any 